# Confusion matrix test-retest reliability (McNemar or paired t-test)

Tags: t-test, reliability, confusion-matrix, mcnemar-test

I would like to ensure test retest reliability between test runs. Each run produces a 2x2 confusion matrix reporting the number of true positives, false positives, false negatives, and true negatives. I've done some initial research, and it seems that the paired t-test or McNemar test may be appropriate for this use case. I am seeking validation though. Are either of these tests appropriate or is there something else I should be using?

[image: 2x2 confusion matrix]

Comment: Neither will be appropriate. Your null will be along the lines of "They are the same," and we do not prove null hypotheses. You might be interested in something like TOST, once you determine your region of practical equivalence.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the response. After doing some additional research, it seems that the McNemar test could be used to determine if changes to the test environment had a statistical significance on the outcome. I could reorganize the confusion matrix to account for total True and total False responses for test1, modify the environment and record the responses for Test2, then use the McNemar test to determine if the change was statistically significant. Does this scenario make sense?

Comment: Yes, you can prove that there is a difference, but you want to show that there is not a difference. What do you do if the p-value comes back with a large value? (Really, you want to know if there is a trivial difference, where you define "trivial" based on the goals of your work.)